# Adding many similar inbox rules in Outlook 365

Tags: outlook.com, outlook-on-the-web, office-365

I want to create several very similar inbox rules in Outlook 365.

In Outlook 2007, I could do this by creating one rule, then use the Copy command and edit the part that needs to change.

In Outlook 365 (running in Internet Explorer), I don't see any way to duplicate an existing rules, only buttons to create a new rule, edit an existing rule, remove a rule, change the order of rules and refresh.

How can I copy-paste or otherwise duplicate a rule? Or how else could I create several similar rules without redoing all the entry work afresh for each rule?